# Why does the open tree of life have 2600 species of rose?

Tags: botany, species-identification, trees

The open tree of life has 2754 species and subspecies with the prefix Rosa.

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Rosa_species) says:

> There is significant disagreement over the number of true rose
>   species. Some species are so similar that they could easily be
>   considered variations of a single species. Lists of rose species
>   usually show between 100 and 150.

The thing is that a subspecies in the open tree taxonomy (OTT) should be written with a different latin name, and I can find at least 400 OTT rosa that are listed as individual species and not subspecies.

Is the OTT not very coherent in terms of accepted species?

Comment: OTT does not claim the taxonomy to be perfect, as it was generated by a synthesis of a lot of existing taxonomies. This might lead to an overrepresentation of some species/subspecies, because they have been classified differently in different taxonomies.